# Typeset directly in Spanish

Tags: emacs, accents, auctex, spanish

I am typesetting in emacs with AucTeX. I generally write in English and Spanish, and, therefore, use the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{soul}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}         
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
óáéí
\end{document
```

I can typeset accent marks with no problems in Textmate, but I get the following error in emacs:

```
ERROR: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:óáéí not set up for use with LaTeX
```

There was a very similar question reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26710/how-to-write-directly-french-characters-in-emacs-and-print-them-in-latex), however, I have not been able to solve my problem the same way. Does anybody know how to set this up?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33628/how-to-use-spanish-accents .

Answer (score 5):

It appears that emacs or some file copying program has translated your document from utf-8 to latin1. If I change

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

to

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

in your document it all works.

Comment: It works for me as well if I make the same change. Do you have any idea what would translate the document to latin1? And/or how to make it stop?

Comment: was it the same document, or did you start with a fresh one? emacs will normally keep documents in the same encoding but for new documents it will use what it thinks is your preferred encoding which may be latin 1 rather than utf8. egreg's answer showed a way of setting the default per file or auctex may have a setting or the basic emacs setting is file-coding-system-alist which says what default encoding to use for each file extension try C-h v file-coding-system-alist

Comment: Strangely enough, the original code works fine for me but if I change to `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} I get a `Missing $ inserted`error.

Comment: @Ricardo this web page is served as utf8, so the characters _are_ in utf8 as seen on the web page, but that doesn't mean that they began life in that encoding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have an awkward setup so I didn't copy paste them. Instead I retyped it. Troubleshooting an unrelated error yesterday I learned that my system is configured to UTF-8, which would explain why the code works for me, but when I change to Latin-1 it fails.

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce the error by saving that code as Latin-1.

Add the "magic line" for Emacs:

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{soul}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}         
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
óáéí
\end{document}
```

and all will be well.

Notice also that the `t1enc` package is obsolete and is still in the distributions for backwards compatibility.