# Encoding error when changing from LaTeX to XeTeX engine in Emacs AucTeX

Tags: xetex, input-encodings

The following MWE works fine when compiling with the LaTeX engine (AUCTeX 11.86)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
áéíóúñ
\end{document}
```

However, with the XeTeX engine I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:áéí not set up for use with LaTeX

--- TeX said ---
.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
```

If I change the input encoding to Latin-1 the document compiles correctly. Why is XeTeX rejecting the UTF-8 encoding?

I tried the suggestions given in [Typeset directly in Spanish](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53827/typeset-directly-in-spanish) and in [AUCTeX and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21200/auctex-and-xetex) but neither help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with XeLaTeX is wrong, because XeTeX directly reads UTF-8 and that package confuses the way it interprets the characters.

Files input to Xe(La)TeX should always be UTF-8 encoded (UTF-16 and UTF-32 work too, but UTF-8 seems preferable). There is the possibility to specify a different input encoding, but this is for legacy documents and is not what you want.

If you want a document that typesets both with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`, then you can try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\begin{document}
áéíóúñ
\end{document}
```

and save the file as UTF-8. You can use `babel` in both cases, since Spanish is based on the Latin alphabet; however, switching to Polyglossia for XeLaTeX may be better:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{spanish}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\begin{document}
áéíóúñ
\end{document}
```

Note that `fontspec` uses by default the OpenType version of the Latin Modern fonts.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I removed the `inputenc` package and now it works as I expected it to. I also saw in one of the log files that XeTeX begs the user not to use `inputenc`. On another note, would specifying `\usepackage{lmodern}` be redundant when using `fonstpec`?

Comment: @Ricardo It's not only redundant, it's actually wrong. :)

Comment: I've taken it out! Should I ask another question as to why it is wrong or can I ask here in the comment section?

Comment: `lmodern.sty` is for enabling the "old style" fonts, while `fontspec`, by default, loads the OpenType version of the Latin Modern fonts

Comment: @egreg hello professor. This question was asked two years ago, but currently, only `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is needed with XeLaTeX

Comment: @doed It's not necessary to load `fontenc` in XeLaTeX; it might be in some cases, but not usually.

Comment: @egreg right, it could be. Languages and their symbols is beyond this comment. I'm not ignoring the fact that XeLaTeX ignores inputenc. But I'm not ignoring either, that for some accented characters like in the op's question: áéíóú for example, `t1enc.def` must be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post that is not longer true. With TeX Live 2020 the MWE of the question now works without problems because the package is now  ignored, producing only a warning, but not a fatal error:

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

This does **not** mean that now use `inputenc` package everywhere is a good practice.