# Exporting accented characters from org-mode to LaTeX

Tags: emacs, accents, org-mode

I'd like to export text from org-mode to LaTeX that contains accented characters. I am using curly brackets, following the guide from the top answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57743/how-to-write-a-and-other-umlauts-and-accented-letters-in-bibliography).

```
# This:
Foo B{\"u}chi automaton bar.
# Exports to:
B\{$\backslash$"u\}chi automaton.

# Whilst this:
#+BEGIN_LATEX
Foo B{\"u}chi automaton bar.
#+END_LATEX
# Exports to:
B{\"u}chi automaton.
```

The question is either:

1. How do I esacape the `{\"}` to avoid the conversion to `{$\backslash$"u\}` ?
2. How do I use LaTeX inline, as `$x$ allows me to use math inline ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you insert directly `ü`?  Org exported LaTeX source loads `inputenc` package with `utf8` option.

Org file:

```
title

äëïöü
```

Exported file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tolerance=1000
\providecommand{\alert}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\title{title}
\author{giordano}
\date{\today}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs Org-mode version 7.9.2}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\vspace*{1cm}

äëïöü

\end{document}
```

If you want to insert inline LaTeX, you can define a dummy macro:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand{\inlinelatex}[1]{#1}

title

\inlinelatex{Foo B{\"u}chi automaton bar.}
```

Comment: Great, that fixed it. I added ü directly into the document. Thanks. I should add that I am using xelatex and pdflatex, which apparently complicates matters with accented characters. But the solution that works for me is described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54573/encoding-error-when-changing-from-latex-to-xetex-engine-in-emacs-auctex Thanks!

Comment: About using XeLaTeX with org-mode see also [How can I use XeLaTeX for LaTeX export instead of pdfLaTeX?](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#using-xelatex-for-pdf-export).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid working with unicode documents (in case the unicode package is not in your system, or this is not configured to insert unicode efficiently) you can also use the Org-mode special symbols: http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html

You can view the predefined symbols by inspecting the org-entities variable:

```
C-h v RET org-entities RET
```

In your case this list contains an entry of the form:

```
("uuml" "\\\"{u}" nil "&uuml;" "ue" "ü" "ü")
```

Then by writting `\uuml` in your org-mode buffer you'll get the desired export.