# ! Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: babel, pdfpages, turkish

I have a problem with the package `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and maybe the reason is 
`\usepackage[turkish]{babel}`. I need to use that package. Can anyone help me, please?

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
 \usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

  \usepackage{sectsty}
  \usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,cite}
  \usepackage{pstcol,pstricks,color}
  \usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{comment}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage[turkish]{babel}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \rhead{Overleaf}
  \chead{X}
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

  \begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \title{XYZ}

  \date{}
  \maketitle
  \vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}



  \section{B}

  \includepdf[pages=-]{putyourpdfhere}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing!

Comment: Do you compile your file with xelatex? I compile your file without any problem with TexLive2019. Also try to put a complete and compilable source code.

Comment: I use Texmaker.

Comment: Please add a minimal example so that everyone can reproduce your problem.

Comment: So go to Configure Texmaker->Quick Build and choose XeLaTeX. Compile your source code again. You probably compile your file with pdfLatex. Also as @AndréC  please out a complete and compilable source code.

Comment: @Probabilitystudent: For me, your example document compiles just fine using `pdflatex` despite of a warning about `pstcol` being obsolete. Could you therefore please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) tat allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: @ADiyanat: From the use of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` I would deduce that the OP uses `pdflatex` as this will lead to a warning in compination with `xelatex`.

Comment: I added my new code. Thanks for you all.

Comment: @leandriis may be this link is useful: (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54573/encoding-error-when-changing-from-latex-to-xetex-engine-in-emacs-auctex)

Comment: @ADiyanat: Sorry, but the problem is not related to the compiler that cone choses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE can be further reduced to the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\section{B}
\includepdf[pages=-]{<document name>}
\end{document}
```

That still produces the error message `Missing \endcsname inserted.`.

As already discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160385/134144), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32178/134144) the `turkish` option of `babel` makes the `=` active. To overcome this, you could use the following if you want to keep shorthands active thoroughout the rest of the document.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\section{B}
\shorthandoff{=}
\includepdf[pages=-]{<document name>}
\shorthandon{=}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use any shorthands throughout the document, you might also be interested in globally turning them off using the `shorthands=off` option as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=off]{babel}

\begin{document}
\section{B}

\includepdf[pages=-]{<document name>}

\end{document}
```

More information on this topic can also be found in section "1.10 Shorthands" of the [`babel` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel).

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, it worked. I had spent more than one hour to fix it but failed. This is a wonderful platform with many great people.